# PhoneGap detecting specific URL in iOS5 UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios5, cordova

I am using PhoneGap for an iOS project and everything is working except I want to detect a click of the logout link in our web app and intercept it with local logout logic. I am able to detect the logout link, but the logic below ALSO thinks it is the logout page when about:blank fires in PhoneGap's UIWebView. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    // If we detect the logout.jsp we need to go back to the login form and reset the credentials
    if ([[url path] rangeOfString:@"logout.jsp"].location == NSNotFound) {
        if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
            return YES;
        }
        else {
            return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
        }
    }
    else {
        // have PhoneGap go back to index page
        NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"www/index" ofType:@"html"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [theWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
        return NO;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I haven't solved why this is happening, so for now I have added this workaround in the main else clause:

```
if ([[url path] rangeOfString:@"about:blank"].location != NSNotFound) {
    return YES;
}
```

The bounty will go to someone who can figure out why I even need that workaround when the initial IF is only checking for the logout.jsp string in the url and about:blank should never match that, but does in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the request url is "about:blank", then `[url path]` returns nil.

So `[nil rangeOfString:@"logout.jsp"].location` return 0 and NSNotFound != 0.

That's why the sentence `([[url path] rangeOfString:@"about:blank"].location != NSNotFound)` is TRUE.

Comment: Ok I'll test this and if that's why my test also works for about:blank I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: +50 - Wow, you're right. This seems odd to me that Objective-C requires that I test twice in case a value is nil. I would assume nil should always be considered NSNotFound when compared to a string. Thanks for figuring it out!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put an NSLog in each call to shouldStartLoadWithRequest?

Comment: I have a breakpoint in there to see what is happening. It is triggering my logout.jsp logic in only two situations. One when the url has logout.jsp as it should and the other when the url is "about:blank"